# Queuing different types of class instances

Tags: c#

I want to enqueue 2 types of class instances into a queue.
For example as follows,

Classes to enqueue)

```
class A{
    int a1;
    int a2;
}
class B{
    string b1;
    string b2;
}
```

Sample1)

```
ConcurrentQueue<Object> queue = ConcurrentQueue<Object>();
queue.Enqueue(new A());
queue.Enqueue(new B());
Object item;
while (queue.TryDequeue(out item))
{
    A a = item as A;
    B b = item as B;
    if(a != null){
    }
    else if(b != null){
    }
}
```

Sample2)

```
class AorB{
    public A a = null;
    public B b = null;
    public AorB(A a){ this.a = a; }
    public AorB(B b){ this.b = b; }
}
ConcurrentQueue<AorB> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<AorB>();
queue.Enqueue(new AorB(new A()));
queue.Enqueue(new AorB(new B()));
AorB item;
while (queue.TryDequeue(out item))
{
    if(item.a != null){
    }
    else if(item.b != null){
    }
}
```

Which is better way, Sample1, Sample2, or others?

Comment: Do A and B share common stuff? How about inheritance?

Comment: Whenever you need to query on type like this, it is likely to be a design problem. It the types are so divergent maybe they shouldn't be stored in the same collection. Alternatively, extract their common behavior to an interface that both classes implement and store them in a collection of such "interfaces".

Comment: Short answer: Others.

Comment: A and B don't have common stuff. They are like a command. For example, one is for printing request and hold texts, another is for beeping one and hold frequency.

Comment: A and B inherits from none now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither of them is actually a good implementation. If (as you mentioned in your comment) they are for commands such as Printing or Beeping and their members are different then you  should be thinking about what they're *doing*. A nicer way around this would be to extract what they're doing into an interface such as

```
public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute();
}
```

Then have A and B implement ICommand so that their printing and beeping are handled by A and B. That way your calling code would become something like:

```
ConcurrentQueue<ICommand> queue = ConcurrentQueue<ICommand>();
queue.Enqueue(new A());
queue.Enqueue(new B());
Object item;
while (queue.TryDequeue(out item))
{
    item.execute();
}
```

This also fits in with "Tell, don't ask".

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect situation to apply the Command pattern.

Have each object implement a common interface that exposes an `Execute` method. Let the object then take care of executing the command through whatever means necessary. By encapsulating the execution of the command into the object itself, this makes the code cleaner and more extensible.

This is Notepad-code, so there might be minor mistakes in syntax.

```
namespace
{
    public interface ICommand
    {
        public void Execute();
    }

    public class CommandA : ICommand
    {
        public int value;

        public void Execute()
        {
            // Do something here
        }
    }

    public class CommandB : ICommand
    {
        public string value;

        public void Execute()
        {
            // Do something here
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private Queue<ICommand> commands = new Queue<ICommand>();

        public Program()
        {
            this.commands.Enqueue(new CommandA());
            this.commands.Enqueue(new CommandB());

            // Much later
            while (item = this.commands.Dequeue())
            {
                item.Execute();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, neither of them. What if you will need to enqueue instances of another class, let say `C`, then your `if` statements will became maintainable.

You have to think about what are going to do with the dequeued items. If you are just storing then in queue, then use two or more queues for each type. In case you'll use them for something no matter of what type they are, then consider using an interface that will the types implement or base class from which the other types will be inherited.

Since you have not provided the use case for this, my advice is abstract.

Comment: Thanks, I notices that this question is abstract and it's important to explain my use case.
My aim seems to be reached by command pattern suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually say neither 1 or 2.

Why don't you use either inheritance if A and B share a common interface, else just two queues, one for each kind of object if they don't have anything common.

And if they don't have anything common, maybe you shouldn't have a single piece of code to use them both too. Two threads, one per type may looks good, depending on the use case.

Comment: Execute orders are important to process each instance in my case, so it needs to enqueue 2 types of intances into same queue. I notice that it is command pattern and try to do it.